# Sudden spike in PHP-FPM process CPU usage. How to track down?

Tags: linux, php, php-fpm, cpu-usage

I have a magento2 store(with 10609 products) running on an ec2 instance(ubuntu 20.04, 16core and 32GB ram). It is a shared server with staging and live on the same instance.

A few days ago, I got an update from amazon saying high cpu usage. when i tracked down Php-fpm logs, slow logs and access logs i observed that there were sudden purging events in the access logs. when i saw PHP-fpm logs it normal.

access logs

```
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
      [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:22 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
. - - [01/Jan/2023:07:32:23 +0300] "PURGE / HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "-"
```

The configuration file of php is  as following:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 70
pm.start_servers = 1
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 7
php_value[upload_tmp_dir] = 
php_value[session.save_path] = 
php_admin_value[error_log] = /home/logs/
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 2048M
pm.max_requests = 500
request_slowlog_timeout = 10
slowlog = /home/logs/php_slow.log
```

The db conf is as following

```
* Fine Tuning
max_connections         = 2000
connect_timeout         = 50
wait_timeout            = 600
max_allowed_packet      = 2048M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size        = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size          = 32M
max_heap_table_size     = 32M

default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 16M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files       = 400
innodb_io_capacity      = 400
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A4w1.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Lk9.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Any entity in the internet may have sent those `PURGE /` requests to your webserver.

It might be an attempt of Denial of Service attack.

There are several options to try to mitigate the issue:

- If Magento does not use `PURGE` requests for anything useful, you can deny them in nginx configuration
- If Magento uses those for some purpose, then you can consider implementing rate-limiting to this endpoint, for example 5 requests / minute. The actual number needs to be determined by Magento usage patterns.

- Rate limiting can be implemented locally with your web server or via a service like Cloudflare.

There is no single setting that can solve this issue magically.